# PHP Traverse through JSON using foreach

Tags: php, json, foreach, google-places-api, geocoding

I had been following this guide to create an app using two different APIs but the guide is old and so one of the APIs does not work like it did in the guide. I am trying to grab coordinates from google geocoding API and stick them into Places for Web. I am new to PHP, so I was following the guide's example to traverse a JSON object but have been stuck all night trying to get it to work. 
Here is the JSON object from the place search API

```
{  
"html_attributions":[  ],
"results":[  
  {  
     "geometry":{  },
     "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
     "id":"d4b0fb0f7bf5b2ea7df896a0c120a68efae039cf",
     "name":"Guadalajara Mexican Grill & Cantina",
     "opening_hours":{  },
     "photos":[  
        {  
           "height":2952,
           "html_attributions":[  ],
           "photo_reference":"CmRaAAAAfO4JKUaO8vCFM2dcu5LMu4mA4_HXQGJ1FyAnyJUre_kD6VOWiQj7tBEECx4AAct5AORIKipSYWg-Zprjlf8o-SFd7mBRGMXMVMwodFZ5KMLwPYPUhBnTTehGPkb9275pEhCkAqMwfmK29vYenk1wdwFvGhSIHR8ch6FONc99tGn4rVnesbuteg",
           "width":5248
        }
     ],
     "place_id":"ChIJ27es4SWa3IARcvjmt3xL2Aw",
     "price_level":2,
     "rating":4.4,
     "reference":"CmRRAAAA7Rx-l7juDX-1or5dfpK6qFcZ0trZ9cUNEUtKP2ziqHb2MhOE6egs-msJ2OdFKEuHhuNe-3Yk6yxUYwxCBqhDT3ci8pYZI4xYhPGyyDgDenbEU_8k84JiEtCGvj4bdIR0EhDR2Pqte5_kDUcCC9PJFVknGhQomvD4d7NBIhCFxI4i2iEc0w9UiA",
     "scope":"GOOGLE",
     "types":[  ],
     "vicinity":"105 North Main Street, Lake Elsinore"
  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  }
],
"status":"OK"
}
```

I am trying to grab all the photo references into an array maybe?, and then plug them into google's Place Photos API. Here is my attempt at that:

### UPDATE

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_GET["location"])){
    //$API_key = "";
    $maps_url = 'https://' .
    'maps.googleapis.com/' .
    'maps/api/geocode/json' .
    '?address=' . urlencode($_GET['location']) .
    '&key=';



    $maps_json = file_get_contents($maps_url);
    $maps_array = json_decode($maps_json, true);

    $lat = $maps_array['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $lng = $maps_array['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

    $places_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?' .
    'location=$lat,$lng' .
    '&radius=1500' .
    '&rankby=distance' .
    '&key=';

    $places_json = file_get_contents($places_url);
    $places_array = json_decode($places_json, true);

    if (!empty($places_array)) {
    foreach ($places_array as $item) {
        var_dump($places_array );
    }
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>What is Here?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <h1>Type in a location</h1>
 <p>This program will display pictures of places to go in that area</p>

  <form action ="">
  <input type ="text" name ="location"/>
  <button type ="submit">Go!</button>
  </form>
  <br/>
  <?php
    echo "$lat $lng";
  ?>
```

Just can't seem to get the foreach loop to do anything

Comment: does var_dump($places_array ) prints something?

Comment: array(3) { ["html_attributions"]=> array(0) { } ["results"]=> array(0) { } ["status"]=> string(15) "INVALID_REQUEST" } array(3) { ["html_attributions"]=> array(0) { } ["results"]=> array(0) { } ["status"]=> string(15) "INVALID_REQUEST" } array(3) { ["html_attributions"]=> array(0) { } ["results"]=> array(0) { } ["status"]=> string(15) "INVALID_REQUEST" }

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: well check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the invalid request means wrong url or bad parameters
if $lat and $lng are variables then the interpolation wont work with single quotes try using double quotes like this
 "location=$lat,$lng"

```
$places_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?' .
"location=$lat,$lng" .
'&rankby=distance' .
'&key=mykey';
```

you should remove radius or distance you cant get both its on the docs
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en-419

here is my modified code that works on localhost please notice the $contextOptions you should not copy this on your code this is a workaround to make  file_get_contents work on my machine

after that the foreach should be easy since is only an array look at the code

```
 $thelocation = "1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA";
$thekey = "someapikey";
$maps_url = 'https://' .
        'maps.googleapis.com/' .
        'maps/api/geocode/json' .
        '?address=' . urlencode($thelocation) .
        '&key=' . $thekey;

$contextOptions = array(
 "ssl" => array(
 "verify_peer"      => false,
 "verify_peer_name" => false,
 ),
);

$maps_json = file_get_contents($maps_url, 0, stream_context_create($contextOptions));// file_get_contents($maps_url);
$maps_array = json_decode($maps_json, true);

$lat = $maps_array['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$lng = $maps_array['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

$places_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?' .
        "location=$lat,$lng" .
        '&rankby=distance' .
        '&key='.$thekey;
//https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&rankby=distance&key=
$places_json = file_get_contents($places_url,0, stream_context_create($contextOptions));
$places_array = json_decode($places_json, true);

if (!empty($places_array)) {


 foreach ($places_array["results"] as $item) {

        echo $item["name"]."<br>";

    }
}
```

this prints....easy

```
AVEonline.co
KRAV MAGA GLOBAL WORLD MAP
Mark Carvalho
Amyan
Moving the Planet
Sosta in Camper
NosCode
GLOBAL BUZZ
OptiClean
JI-SU TELECOM
Reel Thrillz
Clío Reconstrucción Histórica
AprimTek
Hayjayshop
NHAV
gitanos.cat
Being Digitall
Directory+
AdExperts
Optical Spectroscopy and Nanomaterials Group
```

Comment: I still get an INVALID REQUEST from var_dump($places_array)

Comment: please try to put that url on your browser with all the values and be sure your api key is not expired

Comment: I updated my key so that's fine now but I still get an invalid request from that site so that means the URL is wrong then. Not sure where though.

Comment: I got the URL to work now but the code still does not... Not sure where to go from here

Comment: well now if the url works then please make a new var_dump($places_array) with those parameter and values

Comment: So, I ended up doing that and I got a crazy amount of text back. I'm not sure where its all coming from but I can't paste it all here

Comment: That's because you are printing out the whole $places_array again and again with your foreach

Comment: I have been trying to print out just certain values from the array but it printing arrayarraryarrayarrayarrayarray is the closest I get to narrowing it down.

Comment: you should do print_r($myvar) not echo

Comment: o boy im testing this on localhost ill update my answer later

Comment: ok now on my localhost is working perfectly you should remove radius or distance you cant get both its on the docs

Comment: While I was able to solve my problem after, I believe your solution is correct. I used a for loop and sizeof() to loop through and then fixed my JSON filepath which was also the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `$lat,$lng` variables or the API call is your first problem, and the foreach loop is the second.

The `json_decode($someJSON, true);` creates an associative array from your json, so you can't use the `->` arrows, those are for the objects. [More about this](https://jonsuh.com/blog/convert-loop-through-json-php-javascript-arrays-objects/).
There's no `$item->photo_reference`, use:

```
$results = $places_array["results"];

foreach ($results as $item) {
    echo $item["photos"]["photo_reference"];
}
```

Comment: It's not throwing any errors but it's still not popping up anywhere on my screen.

Comment: It's already there. Or where did you mean exactly? I have  $places_array = json_decode($places_json, true); right before the if statement

Comment: From your comment above on var_dump($places_array)

Comment: oh okay. I see what you are saying. Where am I going wrong then :\ It is not recognizing $places_array as an array

Comment: Maybe the $lat,$lng variables not defined in your $places_url

Comment: Let me post all of my code because I think those variables should be okay where they are

Comment: invalid request means some parameters or the url are bad

Comment: 'location=$lat,$lng' . should be with double quotes or else the string interpolation wont work

Comment: Based on your updated answer, foreach did not produce anything when I updated my code and ran it again.

Comment: i think the foreach wont produce anything if your variable is not filled with the correct json are you sure you are getting any data from the url?